# How to disable Peek/Heads up notifications on LG G5 with Android N

Tags: lg, 7.0-nougat, lg-g5

I've read in Android N it's possible to disable Peek/Heads up notifications on by [turning on "Show full importance settings" in System UI Tuner](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidPreviews/comments/4hcfin/how_to_disable_peekheads_up_notifications_on/), but I can't seem to find such on option on my LG G5 with Android N.

How do I disable Peek/Heads up notifications on LG G5 with Android N?

Answer (score 1):

are you looking just to shut off the notifications?

If so:
from the Home page -> Pull down from the top and click on the Sprocket (or Settings) -> If you have the Grid View click on the Sounds&Notification -> Click on Apps -> Scroll down and click on Settings

From here, you can control you want the Peek, but making silent, or click on the Lock Screen and Hide all notifications.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Anthony, but on Apps > Settings you control the Settings app notifications, not all the notifications for all the apps. I am looking for a way to disable the Peek/Heads Up notifications for all the apps, system-wide.